# how to remove text in textbox, when clicked in it first time?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I was trying to make simple Windows mobile app. In which there is login and registration

I want to know how to code  this textbox.text value remove when user focuse or click on it. Like WE do in HTML5 .

```
<input type="text" name="user" placeholder="User Name "/>
```

This how we do in html5 and the text disappear. That I want know how to do it in window app

```
<TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,254,0,0" 
         Name="Username" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the GotFocus Event:

```
<TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,254,0,0" 
         Name="UsernameTextBox" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" 
         GotFocus="YourGotFocusEvent"/>
```

In code Behind:

```
public void YourGotFocusEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   UsernameTextBox.Text = string.empty;
   // if you want this to happen only the first time you can remove the event handler like this
   UsernameTextBox.GotFocus -= YourGotFocusEvent;
}
```

Comment: but this is not like placeholder . it was like watermark style . and when user enter the text it normal text

Answer (score 0):

or handle a Click event. double-click a button in designer and then write

```
this.Text= string.empty
```

Answer (score 0):

For water-mark style text box, you can check out the following UI library.
MahApps provides a set of attached properties for the textbox that allows you to do watermark quite easilly.

See this link -> http://mahapps.com/controls/textbox.html